# needless/redundant cinema?

Tags: word-choice

If a director produces awful films, which he would better spare the world--can one call it "needless cinema"? or maybe "redundant cinema"? Or (if both sound bad), which word would be more suitable to convey the notion of "which would be better spared the world"?

Comment: I'd be more inclined to rephrase it to something like  "his movies are a complete waste of film."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Redundant" can mean unneeded in the sense that's it's duplicative.

> No matter how good the resulting film, it would be redundant to remake
>   *Casablanca*.

"Needless," on the other hand carries a pejorative sense and has the echo of the common phrase "needless waste."

Answer (score 1):

I don't think either needless or redundant convey that the film is awful.

I would say **worthless** is a better word.

But I suggest **[razzie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Raspberry_Awards)**-worthy cinema is a more interesting way to say it.

> The Golden Raspberry Awards, often shortened to the Razzies, is an
>   award ceremony in recognition of the worst in film.

(wikipedia)

Comment: **Worthless** (or pointless) would work best indeed. The point is, that I cite a speaker in a foreign language, and try to be as faithful as possible to the original wording as long as I can retain the original meaning. I was hoping that, as deadrat suggested, "needless" would bring to mind the sense of "needless waste", but if you believe it sounds odd, I'll give it a second thought.

Comment: @stultissimus not odd and not necessarily inappropriate. Needless does have some negative feel to it but not much. Only you can say how apt it is. Needless obviously means there was no need for it. Worthless means it has no value (which, I think it's fair to say would mean no redeeming features). It could be very inappropriate if the film made a lot of money. But then it would be hard to make a case that it was needless either.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to emphasize the "which would be better spared the world" aspect of the director's work, you can gain an alliterative edge by calling it **superfluous cinema**, where *superfluous* means simply "not needed: unnecessary," according to *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003).

If, on the other hand, you want to focus on the extreme awfulness of the finished product, you can achieve the same edge by describing the director's output as **fubar films**, where *fubar* is an acronym describing something that is messed up "beyond all recognition [or *redemption*]."

Answer (score -2):

Neither of those addresses the issue of quality. He might have made a superlative film but one that breaks no new ground, which would make it redundant and needless, but not awful.